# My baked images bleed into eachother

Tags: uv, baking

[image: .]

Hi. I am learning Blender for few months at this point. I know the reason of bleeding problem is in the UV editor. The islands of faces didn't match of baked colours. My baking settings are Cycles, *Bake Type: Diffuse* and *Contributors*: only *Color*.

What can I do dodge this problem? In low-poly models I can increase island distance or paint myself the wrong areas. Can someone tell me what can I do? I try increase resolution of UV image from 1024 to 2048 px. It helped but didn't solve the problem.

Have a good day and thanks to everyone who has read this.